# STM32F0: Interrupt on EXTI1 / EXTI2 not firing, while EXTI4 is working. *confused*

Tags: arm, interrupt, stm32, stm32f0

can you please help me out here and tell me what I am doing wrong? EXTI1 and EXTI2 will not fire, while EXTI4 is however working flawlessly. It's not the hardware. If I switch the pins, the new EXTI4 button will keep firing, while the button that I switched it with doesn't anymore.

I have thoroughly checked all segments, and I cannot figure out why EXTI0_1_IRQHandler doesn't fire, while EXTI4_15_IRQHandler does. Please see the two files below that I use for the library. I'm using SPL with OpenSTM32 IDE. "main.c" only calls

```
ENCODER_STM32_configureInterface();
```

so there really isn't anything else going on.

```
// ENCODER_STM32 library: This library shall enable interfacing an encoder on an STM32F0 chip.

// GPIO Definitions
#define    ENCODER_GPIO_PORT       GPIOA
#define    ENCODER_GPIO_CLK_PIN    GPIO_Pin_1
#define    ENCODER_GPIO_DT_PIN     GPIO_Pin_2
#define    ENCODER_GPIO_SW_PIN     GPIO_Pin_4
#define    ENCODER_GPIO_PERIPH     RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOA

// EXTI Definitions
#define    ENCODER_EXTI_PORTSRC    EXTI_PortSourceGPIOA
#define    ENCODER_EXTI_CLK_PINSRC EXTI_PinSource1
#define    ENCODER_EXTI_CLK_LINE   EXTI_Line1
#define    ENCODER_EXTI_DT_PINSRC  EXTI_PinSource2
#define    ENCODER_EXTI_DT_LINE    EXTI_Line2
#define    ENCODER_EXTI_SW_PINSRC  EXTI_PinSource4
#define    ENCODER_EXTI_SW_LINE    EXTI_Line4
#define    ENCODER_EXTI_PERIPH     RCC_APB2Periph_SYSCFG
#define    ENCODER_EXTI_MODE       EXTI_Mode_Interrupt
#define    ENCODER_EXTI_TRIGGER    EXTI_Trigger_Falling

// NVIC Definitions
#define    ENCODER_NVIC_CLK_CHA    EXTI0_1_IRQn
#define    ENCODER_NVIC_DT_CHA     EXTI2_3_IRQn
#define    ENCODER_NVIC_SW_CHA     EXTI4_15_IRQn
#define    ENCODER_NVIC_PRIORITY   0x03

// Variable Definitions

// Parameter Definitions

// Function Definitions

// Function Declarations
void ENCODER_STM32_configureInterface(void);
```

and...

```
#include "stm32f0xx.h"
#include "usart_stm32_console.h"
#include "encoder_stm32.h"

void ENCODER_STM32_configureInterface(void) {

    // Enabling Clocks
    RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(ENCODER_GPIO_PERIPH, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(ENCODER_EXTI_PERIPH, ENABLE);

    // Configuring GPIO
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = ENCODER_GPIO_CLK_PIN | ENCODER_GPIO_DT_PIN | ENCODER_GPIO_SW_PIN;
    GPIO_Init(ENCODER_GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    // Configuring EXTI
    EXTI_InitTypeDef EXTI_InitStructure;
    EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_Line = ENCODER_EXTI_CLK_LINE | ENCODER_EXTI_DT_LINE | ENCODER_EXTI_SW_LINE;
    EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_Mode = ENCODER_EXTI_MODE;
    EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_Trigger = ENCODER_EXTI_TRIGGER;
    EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_LineCmd = ENABLE;
    SYSCFG_EXTILineConfig(ENCODER_EXTI_PORTSRC, ENCODER_EXTI_CLK_PINSRC);
    SYSCFG_EXTILineConfig(ENCODER_EXTI_PORTSRC, ENCODER_EXTI_DT_PINSRC);
    SYSCFG_EXTILineConfig(ENCODER_EXTI_PORTSRC, ENCODER_EXTI_SW_PINSRC);
    EXTI_Init(&EXTI_InitStructure);

    // Configuring NVIC
    NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = ENCODER_NVIC_CLK_CHA | ENCODER_NVIC_DT_CHA | ENCODER_NVIC_SW_CHA;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPriority = ENCODER_NVIC_PRIORITY;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
    NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

}


void EXTI0_1_IRQHandler(void) {

    USART_STM32_sendToUSART("IRQ0_1 triggered");

    if(EXTI_GetITStatus(ENCODER_EXTI_CLK_LINE) != RESET) {
        USART_STM32_sendToUSART("CLK triggered");
        EXTI_ClearITPendingBit(ENCODER_EXTI_CLK_LINE);
    }

}


void EXTI2_3_IRQHandler(void) {

    USART_STM32_sendToUSART("IRQ2_3 triggered");

    if(EXTI_GetITStatus(ENCODER_EXTI_DT_LINE) != RESET) {
        USART_STM32_sendToUSART("DT triggered");
        EXTI_ClearITPendingBit(ENCODER_EXTI_DT_LINE);
    }

}


void EXTI4_15_IRQHandler(void) {

    USART_STM32_sendToUSART("IRQ4_15 triggered");

    if(EXTI_GetITStatus(ENCODER_EXTI_SW_LINE) != RESET) {
        USART_STM32_sendToUSART("SW triggered");
        EXTI_ClearITPendingBit(ENCODER_EXTI_SW_LINE);
    }

}
```

Comment: I've tried with HAL via CubeMX, and it's working, thus it cannot be an issue with an overload of components activated. There is something wrong with the code in SPL config as above that stops it from working. I just can't see it.

Comment: Who cares about SPL which is already dead 5 years. Anyway in my personal opinion writing such a simple routines using those "great" libraries like HAL or SPL is just ridiculous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`NVIC_Init()` works with a single interrupt at a time**, because `NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel` is not a bitmask, but a simple identifier.

Look at the definition of the IRQ channels in the header:

```
  EXTI0_1_IRQn                = 5,      /*!< EXTI Line 0 and 1 Interrupts                            */
  EXTI2_3_IRQn                = 6,      /*!< EXTI Line 2 and 3 Interrupts                            */
  EXTI4_15_IRQn               = 7,      /*!< EXTI Line 4 to 15 Interrupts                            */
```

Or'ing them together like mask bits makes no sense, but in this particular case, 5|6|7 yields 7, which accidentally equals the number of the EXTI4 interrupt, that's why this button works.

Simply call `NVIC_Init()` three times:

```
NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = ENCODER_NVIC_CLK_CHA;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPriority = ENCODER_NVIC_PRIORITY;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = ENCODER_NVIC_DT_CHA;
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = ENCODER_NVIC_SW_CHA;
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);
```

Comment: Thank you! This really helped me understand. Sorry for such a rookie question. My first times working with STM platform.